# Multiple divs taking up the same container size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a basic slideshow system. The way it works is that there's a container that contains multiple slides:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="slide active"></div>
   <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Only 1 slide is active.

Now I'm trying to introduce a fade-in effect. In order to do this, for a brief moment 2 slides will be visible at the same time.

I'm animating this jQuery's animate function.

Before this it was pretty easy for every `.slide` to just take up 100% width and height of it's parent, but this no longer works well when I'm stacking multiple `.slide`s with different z-indexes.

I thought of just using `display: absolute`, but I was not able to let every `.slide` take up exactly the size of `.container`.

Testing css:

```
.container {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
}

.slide {
   opacity: 50%;

}
```

My question:

How can I have two `.slide` elements take up the exact same space (100% of it's parent's width and height) without specifying absolute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use position `relative` and `absolute` together, you can use this trick.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.slide {
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.active {
  background: aqua;
  z-index: 1; /*this slide should on top of the other one*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="slide active"></div>
   <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```